# Why doesn’t “king” have an article in “The lion is king of the jungle”?

Tags: grammar, articles

I am learning articles and trying to understand some edge cases.

Help me to decipher the role (the meaning) of articles in this sentence:

> The lion is king of the jungle.

1. `The lion` - is a generic reference to all lions as a class. It can be changed to `Lions`: `Lions are kings of the jungle`, the meaning will remain the same.

   - How did I understand it is the generic reference? Because it is the first occurrence of the word `lion` in the text, but it is preceded by the `The` article. It suggests the author wasn't implying a specific instance of lion (his pet, for example), but a species in the family Felidae.
   - `A lion` in this case is valid grammatically, but the meaning will change to "any member of the lion species", not the species as whole.
   - [The article about generic nouns](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html).
   - [The definite article with a whole class](https://www.grammaring.com/the-definite-article-with-a-whole-class).
2. `king of the jungle`

   - `king` - in my opinion this noun should have the `the` article. Because it is singular and countable, therefore some article is necessary if it is not exception. The `a` article isn't suitable here, because the `king` noun is specified by the `of the jungle` construction: which king? - `of the jungle`, not any general king. May be the **king** title  doesn't require an article, like `breakfast`, `basketball`, etc? But this rule says no - [The definite article with titles and positions](https://www.grammaring.com/the-definite-article-with-titles-and-positions).
   - `the jungle` - the same meaning as in the `The lion` case. Generic reference to all jungles as a class, because it is the first occurrence of the `jungle` word in the text and has the `the` article. Also interchangeable with `jungles`.

**Result:** Lions (species, general) are the kings (title, specific) of jungles (land cover, general).

**Two questions:**

1. Is my interpretation correct?
2. Why doesn't `king` have the `the` article?

**Note** - The  [Oxford Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/king?q=king) says: "The lion is the king of the jungle."

Comment: This has already been addressed here at https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/104195/l-am-a-young-king-but-l-am-king-why-no-article-in-front-of-the-second-king/104200#104200 in Lawrence's answer. According to Masters, the null article (not the zero article) is even more definite than the definite article. Like the zero article, it is 'invisible'.

Comment: He must be king of the hill.

Answer (score 6):

All the grammar points presented are fine.

But in this case, please note that "**king of the jungle**" is a **set phrase** and therefore does not need an article, as in:

She is **queen for the day**. [an old  TV show]. Please note though: **It is not a mistake to say:** The lion is the king of the jungle. or: Lions are the kings of the jungle. But you **lose the edginess** of the set phrase. :)

This is just one of those terrible exceptions that make English a b****.

Comment: I looked into the  [Oxford Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/king?q=king), it says: "The lion is the king of the jungle." Also, I understood why the `a` article isn't suitable here. I added these notes into the question.

Comment: I said: "The lion is the king of the jungle." is fine. Why repeat it?? Also, I answered your question. "The lion is a king in the jungle" is fine, too, but means something else. It means he is not a king elsewhere. I really don't know what else you want.

Comment: "Why repeat it" - because it is additional information to your answer. You  said - I found the confirmation and add reference. It is useful for someone else, who will read this page in the future. I often do so.

Comment: No, it is not additional information to my answer. **It is my answer. I did not say "I found confirmation". The reference is my own knowledge, which is why I posted the answer. But  here is a reference for you: king of the hill, for example, which functions the exactly same way**: http://advanceinenglish.com/what-are-idioms-why-are-they-important-for-fluency/

Comment: @Lambie "The lion is a king in the jungle" means he is not a king elsewhere? Can you give more examples to elucidate this usage of "a king"? Thanks a million in advance.

Comment: @joy2020 The lion is **a king in the jungle but just a wild animal** in a zoo. //He's a pain in class but an angel at home.

Comment: @Lambie Can you compare it with "The lion is the king in the jungle but just a wild animal in a zoo. " :)

Comment: @Lambie Also, does it always mean he is not a king elsewhere. What about "The lion is a king in the jungle, so we should respect the lion."

Comment: @joy2020 the and a: specific versus a generality. He is the head honcho in the office but just a man in a boat on weekends.