# Why do we need 'the' in front of the grammar word?

Tags: definite-article

> the indefinite article
>
> the gerund
>
> the past participle

I've always thought that 'the' is placed when you're talking about something specific. But I see people usually say with 'the' even though you're discussing something general, such as

> In English grammar, the past participle refers to an action that was started and completed entirely in the past.

Why is that so?

Comment: "The tiger is found in India". That is a specific kind of creature, not a specific tiger.

Comment: The past participle is a specific element of English grammar.

Comment: @WeatherVane What about "in the past"?

Comment: My [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/225314/70412) can be useful for you. It has some information about this topic.